# How is the substitution $t \mapsto it$ an analytic continuation?

Tags: complex-analysis, mathematical-physics, analytic-continuation

In quantum theory it is common to use what is known as Wick rotation, which says for a function defined over $\mathbb{R}^n$, for at least one of the variables, make the substitution $t \mapsto it.$ So for example, we may have
$$f(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n) \mapsto f(ix_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n).$$
It is said that such a transformation is an analytic continuation.

How is this an analytic continuation if they no longer share a common open set in their respective domains? In the example above, the only set they share is $\{0, x_2,, \ldots, x_n : x_2, \ldots, x_n \in \mathbb{R} \}$ but this is not open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's recall that an analytic continuation consists in extending the domain of definition of an analytic function (and keeping analytic properties at the same time).

In quantum mechanics, we usually work with wavefunctions $f : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, which are extended to $\tilde{f} : \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ in a first step and **then** are Wick-rotated in a second step, i.e. $\tilde{f}(z_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n) \mapsto \tilde{f}(iz_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Wick's rotation isn't an analytic continuation itself but assumes such one.

In conclusion, $f$ is analytically continuated before the transformation due to Wick's rotation and the common open subset among the domains of definition is simply given by $D_1 \cap D_2 = \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{R}^{n-1} \cap \mathbb{R}^n = \mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: So we assume that we are able to analytically continue $f$ to all of $\mathbb{C}$? Isn't this a big assumption to make? But suppose we make that assumption, then is a Wick rotation just a restriction to the imaginary axis?

Comment: Physicists are not afraid of assumptions, to say the least ! No, there is no restriction in the process : 1) the domain of the problem is extended; 2) Wick's rotation is applied to the whole complex plane (it is a linear transformation, not a restriction of any kind); 3) the initial problem is solved in this new setup; 4) finally, Wick's rotation is inversed to recover the solution in the original space. The purpose of such manipulations is the simplification of the problem by treating it in a new space, in the same manner as the Fourier transform does.

Comment: Thank you. So we assume that we are able to analytically continue $f$, then apply the linear transformation $t \mapsto it$, do our analyses, and then convert back by inverting the linear transformation. I think I got it now. The only part that I'm still uncomfortable with is the assumption that we may analytically continue $f$ to all of $\mathbb{C}$, I know physicists do not hesitate to make such assumptions but I have even seen this analytic continuation being carried out in rigorous mathematical physics so I thought there must be some justification.

Comment: Not OP and late to the party, but do you really need an analytical extension? Isnt a smooth extension sufficient in most cases? It is less of an assumption, unless you really need it to be holomorphic in the "time variable".